# x-editable control with typeaheadjs issue

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, x-editable

I cannot seem to get the 'on' event to work within this x-editable control

I have tried it as a stand alone function and within the x-editable project and neither will fire... I am trying to grab the the data value of the selected item that is stored in the datum object.   Any thoughts>?

```
$('#cReferralID').editable({
    // url: '/Update/Client',
    name: 'hi',
    typeahead: {
        name: 'referall',
         remote: {
             url: 'Search/ReferNameLookup?q=%QUERY'
         }

    }.on('typeahead:selected', function ($e, data) {

        alert("selected: " + data.value + " datum - " + data.data);
        selected = data;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I overcome my similar issue

```
  $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.hasClass('tt-dataset-referall')) {
      //element with #someID was inserted.
      var $input = $target.closest('.twitter-typeahead');
      $input.off('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted');
      $input.on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', function(e, data) {
        alert("selected: " + data.value + " datum - " + data.data);
        selected = data;
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

When do you want it to be triggered ?

If it is on save, do a :

```
$('#cReferralID').on('save', function(e, params) {
    alert('Saved value: ' + params.newValue);
});
```

If it is as soon as the popup shows (or inline form) :

```
$('#cReferralID').on('shown', function(e, editable) {
    editable.input.$input.val('overwriting value of input..');
});
```